# Where to creating properties file for reading values in a Web application deployed on Weblogic(Linux)

Tags: java, linux, web-applications, properties

I have a Web application consisting of JSPs, Servlets and Java classes developed in Jdeveloper in Windows.

This applicaiton need to be deployed as WAR in Weblogic over a linux box. Some of the servlet and Java classes have certain values hardcoded. I want to avoid this but for obvious reasons. Therfore I was thinking of using the properties file.

Now where do i create this properties file in my jdeveloper so that when i create war file of it and and deploy to a Weblogic server, i have access to this Properties file or how should i code it my program so that wherever I put this properties file on my linux like \u01\cap\domain\machine\domain_name\readvalues.properties. t is able to read it.

and then how do i mention the path in linux. Can you please help me with the code

Answer (score 2):

Stick the properties file in your war file and access it like you would any other properties file via:

```
props.load(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/someProps.properties"));
```

The best place to put the properties file is in the /WEB-INF/classes folder. So you need to load the properties files relative to that.

Comment: but on my weblogic deployed over linux system how would i access this properties file.Suppose I have deployed the WAR file.Now I need to change certain content in the properties file.Where i gonna find this file

Comment: I don't know where you put the properties file but you can always do 'jar -tf name.war' to see what is inside the war.